# Social links for each user

Tags: 7

I am looking a module which will give each user an option to create links to various social networks profiles they have.

I found Follow module but for D7 it says it is very unstable.

Comment: do you mean the user can create links to their social profiles on their Drupal profile page?

Comment: yep, or a block that will be visible on every page created by that user. But for start at least on their profile page.

Answer (score 0):

For the profile part, you can just use the [profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module. It allows you to add any kind of field to user profiles. Install it, enable it, clear caches, and go to structure > profile types.  For the actual fields, you might want to use the [url field](https://drupal.org/project/url) module, to enable validation of urls, etc. You can then create all the url fields you want, and give them appropriate names, like "facebook page", "twitter page" etc.

To display a block on nodes authored by the user, you could do the following:

- Create a view of profiles.
- Create a block display for the view
- Choose fields (your social media link fields)
- Click on advanced and then "contextual filter"
- Add "profile: user uid" as a contextual filter and click 'apply'
- Under "When the filter value is NOT in the url", select "Provide default value"
- Select "PHP code"
- Paste in the following PHP:

  $node = menu_get_object();
  return $node->uid;
- Click "apply" and then save your view.

You can now add your block to the content types your users are allowed to create.

Comment: Thx for helping out. I know how to do all you have written but i need a little bit more. For example i case you mention i would have to search and implement icon for each field and make them visible (without text) only if user has a value in it. I am surprised Drupal has not some kind of module for this. It is very common request on many sites.

Comment: To display fields with icons, you'd have to write some css. Are you comfortable with that?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Social media](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialmedia) module. It has functionality to allow each user to link to their own social media profiles.